# Can I use cream cheese in a sauce?

Tags: substitutions, sauce, cream-cheese

I made a white sauce with butter flour and milk, intending to add cheddar for a cheese sauce.  Then I realized I'd run out the day before.  Could I have used Philadelphia cream cheese instead?  I'm in the UK if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently use Cream Cheese in situations like this, but I would generally go for one of the Garlic and Herb or Chive flavoured ones (If using Philadelphia itself.) Alternatively, Lidl and Aldi do, to my taste, much superior Cream Cheeses ...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. The taste will be obviously different, but I don't expect any consequence that would make it unpalatable to the average person. You would be better off if you start with softened cream cheese, but if all you have now is fridge-cold cream cheese, that should work too.

Comment: It won't be unpalatable, just tasteless.  And not all cream cheeses will react well to being heated up a lot.  I'd skip it entirely

Comment: I would disagree with the "tasteless" part. For me, even pure bechamel has a taste, and a Mornay with cream cheese has more taste than bechamel. Maybe even more than of made with bad cheddar. The hearing behavior is a good point, for me cream cheese (Philadelphia style, not turro like styles) melts well, but I can easily imagine that the are brands which don't, and at some point we had a question where somebody asserted that Philadelphia itself has very different textures on different continents.

Comment: True, Philadelphia is not exactly the same on different continents/countries.  Although personally I think it's pretty tasteless everywhere, or at least that waxy texture makes my tongue curl. And of course bechamel has a taste :-).  But I was assuming most people would be using Philadelphia, even though I usually get Trader Joe's cream cheese, which has a lot more taste, sorry for the prejudice